# How Java and C# threads deal with data synchronisation differently?

Tags: c#, java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

In the following C# code, t1 always(for the times I tried) finishes.

```
class MainClass
{
    static void DoExperiment ()
    {
        int value = 0;

        Thread t1 = new Thread (() => {
            Console.WriteLine ("T one is running now");
            while (value == 0) {
                //do nothing
            }
            Console.WriteLine ("T one is done now");
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread (() => {
            Console.WriteLine ("T two is running now");
            Thread.Sleep (1000);
            value = 1;
            Console.WriteLine ("T two changed value to 1");
            Console.WriteLine ("T two is done now");
        });

        t1.Start ();
        t2.Start ();

        t1.Join ();
        t1.Join ();
    }

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            DoExperiment ();
            Console.WriteLine ("------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

But in the Java code which is very similar, t1 never(for the times I tried) exits:

```
public class MainClass {
static class Experiment {
    private int value = 0;

    public void doExperiment() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                System.out.println("T one is running now");
                while (value == 0) {
                    //do nothing
                }
                System.out.println("T one is done now");
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("T two is running now");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                value = 1;
                System.out.println("T two changed value to 1");
                System.out.println("T two is done now");
            }
        }
        );

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t1.join();
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        new Experiment().doExperiment();
        System.out.println("------------------------");
    }
}
```

}

Why is that?

Comment: You might be interested in reading the Java Memory Model.

Comment: What is compiler settings in case of C#. You should try x86 Release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things here.

Firstly, when you do:

```
t1.Start ();
t2.Start ();
```

You're asking the operating system to schedule the threads for runnings. It's possible that `t2` will start first. In fact it may even finish before `t1` is ever scheduled to run.

However, there is a memory model issue here. Your threads may run on different cores. It's possible that `value` is sitting in the CPU cache of each core, or is stored in a register on each core, and when you read/write to `value` you are writing to the cache value. There's no requirement for the language runtime to flush the writes to `value` back to main memory, and there's no requirement for it to read the value back from main memory each time.

If you want to access a shared variable then it's your responsibility to tell the runtime that the variable is shared, and that it must read/write from main memory and/or flush the CPU cache. This is typically done with `lock`, `Interlocked` or `synchronized` constructs in C# and Java. If you surround access to `value` with a `lock` (in C#) or `synchronized` (in Java) then you should see consistent results.

The reason things behave differently without locking is that each language defines a memory model, and these models are different. Without going into the specifics, C# on x86 writes back to main memory more than the Java memory model does. This is why you're seeing different outcomes.

Edit: For more information on the C# side of things take a look at [Chapter 4](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) of Threading in C# by Joseph Albahari.

Comment: `Without going into the specifics, C# on x86 writes back to main memory more than the Java memory model does` - while I've not much ideas about the C# memory model, I seriously doubt that it requires T1 to terminate. Seems more like a implementation detail how it gets optimised.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how it happens in C#, but what happens in Java is `JVM` optimization. The value of `value` does not change inside the `while` loop and the `JVM` recognises it and just skip the test and change your bite code to something like this:

```
while (true) {
    // do nothing
}
```

In order to fix this in java you need to declare `value` as `volatile`:

```
private volatile int value = 0;
```

This will make the `JVM` to not optimise this `while` loop and check the for the **actual** value of `value` at the start of each iteration.

Comment: +1 http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/demonstrating-when-volatile-is-required.html